# Rendering problems of flex column boxes in Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having some rendering problems in Firefox and Safari.

My flex column boxes are 33% each and should go horizontally across the screen. They do that in IE and Chrome. In Firefox and Safari, the information is display in one column vertically down the page.

What do I need to add to my CSS to get it to render correctly in Firefox and Safari?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/4rj47uvn/10/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container-3col">
<div class="box-3col-1">
                <img alt="Banana" height="173" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYVRpzJ_BgMuSti8xSqtLjWQoQ3Y4unc7fc5XCsh6jMw3kQchLCnBs3oU" width="173" />
    <p>
        The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p></div>
    <div class="box-3col-2">
        <img alt="Apple" height="173" src="http://dreamatico.com/data_images/apple/apple-6.jpg" width="173" />
    <p>
        The apple tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-3col-3">
        <img alt="Orange" height="173" src="https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/KRLMkuaBjm5mKDDP" width="173" />
    <p>
        The orange tree (Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple.</p>          
       </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.container-3col {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.container-3col > div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box-3col-1 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.box-3col-2 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.box-3col-3 {
    width: 33.33333%;
}
```

Comment: I do not see the issue in Firefox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33803922/3597276

Answer (score 0):

You need vendor prefixes:

```
.container-3col {
    display: -webkit-box;      /* iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* old versions of firefox (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* old versions of IE */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* old versions of chrome and safari */
    display: flex;             /* correct according to spec */
 }
```

Comment: Where do I put that in the CSS?

Comment: Wherever you need the property `display: flex;` ... which prefixes you need depend on which browsers (and versions) you need to support. There are autoprefixing tools that can automated the insertion of these prefixes for you. Also bear in mind that other flexbox properties, such as justify-content may also need vendor prefixes. Google "autoprefixing css" to see what options are out there.

Comment: Can you show me in the jsfiddle? I tried adding the prefixes and it's still giving me rendering problems

Comment: This isn't completely true and only IE will need those. It depends on the version of the other browsers but, for example, Chrome hasn't needed it since version 21 and Firefox since 22(?)

Comment: As I said, it all depends on which browser and versions you need to support. Load this in safari and you should see they load side-by-side: http://jsfiddle.net/agentfitz/ymofxxk0/1/

Comment: Except your list says "NEW - Chrome" and Chrome doesn't need it. But I don't see the issue in Firefox either.